# Why isn't my Reducer reading in a file?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I've got a method that creates a hashtable from a .txt file, and uses that hashtable to assign values to words in the Value passed to the Reducer. Here is how I am attempting to do it:

```
@Override
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
    Path pt = new Path("hdfs:/user/jk/sentiwords.txt");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line!=null) {
        String[] split =  line.split("\t");
        String word = split[0].substring(0, split[0].length() - 2);
        double score = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
        int hashCode = word.hashCode();
        sentiTable.put(hashCode, score);
        line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
```

It is then used in this method, which is called on each Value in the key/value pair:

```
public double analyzeString(String str) {
    double stringScore = 0.0;
    String[] strArr = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (String segment: strArr) {
        int hashedSeg = segment.hashCode();

        if (sentiTable.containsKey(hashedSeg)) {
            double value = (double) sentiTable.get(hashedSeg);
            stringScore += value;
        }
    }
    return stringScore;
}
```

Ideally, this ought to return a number between -1 and 1. In reality, it always returns 0.

Edit:

I should note that sentiTable is created in the class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting 0 as a result probably means that nothing is being read from this file. I see two things that might have gone wrong:

1. Wrong path: I think that hdfs paths should start with `hdfs://...`, instead of `hdfs:/...`.
2. Wrong imports for Path and FileSystem. Make sure that you import the ones provided by Hadoop.

You can always print a message in the setup method to see if the file has been found.

Extra: You might want to reconsider your containment checks, as many collisions are expected when using the hashCode of Strings in big data.

Comment: I figured it out - The file I was reading in had a formatting error! It was supposed to be tab delimited, and mostly was, but some new lines snuck in at some point. I appreciate the help